Is there any way to Zoom in to address (place) on google maps (fill viewport)
I am using the places autocomplete API along with the google maps api.
The place object returns a geometry.viewport, which you can set the map to fit:
map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport); 

However, this viewport returned from the places API is quite massive. For example, the places API for a home address returns a viewport that covers most of the neighborhood. My goal is, when the user selects an address from the places API, the map is zoomed in such that the address fills almost the entire viewport.
Is that possible with the places API or another google API?

Use either zoom level or latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta depening on how your showing the map and on what device?
